# Warning when running pod update on CocoaPods 0.39.0

Tags: ios, swift, swift2, cocoapods

I get the following warning when I run pod update command. I checked that "$(inherited)" is already added in the build settings.

I tried settiong "EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT" to both yes and no and I get this warning in either case.

```
The `Project Name[Debug]` target overrides the `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` build setting defined in `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig'. This can lead to problems with the CocoaPods installation
    - Use the `$(inherited)` flag, or
    - Remove the build settings from the target.
```

Answer (score 0):

I think that the parameter `EMBEDDED_CONTENT_CONTAINS_SWIFT` under `Building Settings` in Xcode `is not equal to` that in file `Pods/Target Support Files/Pods/Pods.debug.xcconfig`.

You could try to make it same on these two points.